# Coverage file is not getting generated using bullseye with XCode

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, bullseye

I am trying to integrate BullsEye 8.14.0 with Xcode 10.12. Following are the steps that I followed:

1. mkdir -p $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents

2.Create the file $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/BullseyeCoverage.plist with contents like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>BullseyeCoverage</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
            <string>setenv</string>
            <string>COVFILE</string>
            <string>path</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Path I have given as $HOME/Desktop/BEC/test123.cov and also tried with Users/myUserName/Desktop/BEC/test123.cov

3. Add an export command like shown below to the file $HOME/.bash_profile.
   export COVFILE=path
4. Added export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/BullseyeCoverage/bin, in .bash_profile as the first entry.
5. Then built the xcode project as usual.

Followed the document https://www.bullseye.com/help/tool-xcode.html, in short.

But after doing all this, I should be seeing a test123.cov file generated after the successful build with all the APIs listed, which I couldn"t see. 
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Just to add, when am trying to compile a simple main.cpp with gcc compiler using command covc gcc -c main.cpp, its generating the coverage file, but the same is not happening with XCode

Comment: Since you are trying to attract attention to your question by misusing answers elsewhere, here is how you should instead do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers